# How to use lipsum with greek as main language

Tags: languages, greek, lipsum

I'm trying to create a random text using lipsum having greek as the main language.
The problem is that when I try to compile my file, an error keeps occuring about `endcsname`.

My code is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{lipsum}    

\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\latintext#1\greektext}

\begin{document}   
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

I also tried to run it using `\eng{\lipsum[2]}`  instead of `\lipsum[2]` but it didn't seem to work. The only way to make it work is to have english as the main language.

Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: Do you have 10 paragraphs of greek text similar to Lorem Ipsum (i.e. aperiodic, random and sensless)? If you do, then we can just make a `greeklipsum` package, or add it directly to `lipsum` ;)

Comment: Interesting thought but I'm a rookie and I don't know how I could possibly do such a thing. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `lipsum` package uses `\roman{lips@count}` to build a control sequence name; but the Greek module for `babel` changes the meaning of `\roman` making it not fully expandable.

Solution: patch the relevant command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\lips@dolipsum
 {\roman{lips@count}}
 {\romannumeral\c@lips@count}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

I've omitted the call to `inputenc` that's not relevant for the example. You should consider switching to UTF-8 rather than using ISO-8859-7.

Comment: By the way, the `kantlipsum` package doesn't suffer from this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! It seems to work perfetly. One question though..why switch to UTF-8 since it produces errors(`! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:μελ not set up for use with LaTeX.`) when I use it?

Comment: @shagwsu You need to ensure your document is saved as UTF-8

Comment: **NOTE** As of version 1.3 of `lipsum` (released 2014-07-27), this patch is no more necessary.